# How to add datasource that will only generate 1 column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to asp.net and currently having troubles with gridtable.

I have a table column from database named `BlogTitle`, `BlogText` and `BlogDate` and this is a current result:

[image]

Now What I want is to gather all of them to only one column without the header title So i can style them: more like this:

[image]

As you can see it is now organize all the data into one column for each of the row without the header title.

current code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="datafile" CssClass="datafileid" runat="server" >
</asp:GridView>
```

server side:

```
var data = (from o in quack.Blogs select new { o.BlogTitle, o.BlogText ,o.BlogDate}).ToList();


        this.datafile.DataSource = data;
        this.datafile.DataBind();
```

How can I do it using gridView to specify only to use one column but use all the data that was pass on it for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of `Repeater` control.. It will help you to display output in single column.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Make use of asp:repeater and in it's item template you can define div(s) which will fulfill your UI need.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely bind one column in `Gridview`. In aspx , you need to specify just one column as bound field, select as many as column in code behind, and then bind to grid. Sample code will be like this.

ASSUMPTION: `BlogTitle` will be the one column you need.

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="datafile" CssClass="datafileid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BlogTitle" HeaderText="BlogTitle" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
var data = (from o in quack.Blogs select new { BlogTitle = o.BlogTitle,BlogText =  o.BlogText,BlogDate= o.BlogDate }).ToList();

this.datafile.DataSource = data;
this.datafile.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use datalist control.
You can design as your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `TemplateField` in the `GridView` and turn off `AutoGenerateColumns`. Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="blogGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Blog post">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="BlogTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogTitle") %>'></asp:Literal>
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="BlogText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogText") %>'></asp:Literal>
                <br />
                <asp:Literal ID="BlogDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BlogDate") %>'></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```